# How to store multiselect data into the database laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm having an issue with an update function on laravel, I'm trying to send data from a multiselect in a form, I want the description of "combos" to have several items stored, and those items I grab them from another table (productos) and put them in a select inside the form. But the problem is that since I'm sending several items I need to send them as an array to store it into the database then I get the error

`array to string conversion`

Here's the function on my controller

```
public function update(Combos $product){

$data = request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|min:8|max:100',
    'id' => 'required',
    'description' =>'required',
]);

$user->where('id',$data['id'])->update($data);

return view('Combos')->with('combos', Combos::all())
                     ->with('products', Products::all());
}
```

Since I'm sending the values through a select in the form:

```
<div class="form-group" id="selector">
<label for="">Products</label>
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="description[]" >
<option value="" disabled>Select product</option>
@foreach ($products as $product)
<option value="{{$product->name}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can pass the list of data as an string (because the column on the database is a string). I've tried using implode() by putting $data['description] inside a variable like this:

```
public function update(Combos $product){

$data = request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|min:8|max:100',
    'id' => 'required',
    'description' =>'required',
]);

$new_desc = implode(" ", $data['description']);
dd($new_desc); //prints "value1 value2 value3" as string, instead of an array

$product->where('id',$data['id'])->update($data);

return view('Combos')->with('combos', Combos::all())
                     ->with('products', Products::all());
}
```

the curious thing is that when I `dd($new_desc)` it does convert the array into a string

Or straight up just placing the `data['description]` inside the `implode()`, but even then it's not working.

```
public function update(Combos $product){

$data = request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|min:8|max:100',
    'id' => 'required',
    'description' =>'required',
]);

implode(" ", $data['description']); 
dd($data['description']); //when I submit the update it still sends the data as an array array:2[0 => 'value1', 1 => value2]

$user->where('id',$data['id'])->update($data);

return view('Combos')->with('combos', Combos::all())
                     ->with('products', Products::all());
}
```

What could I do in this case to send this list of items from the multiselect as a string instead of an array, or how do I convert them to string before sending the update? I would be really thankful if someone could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Store implode(" ", $data); into some variable and use that variable in update  function.

Comment: how could I add it to the update function? (the function is: `$user->where('id',$data['id'])->update($data);`)

Comment: `<option value="{{$product->name}}">{{$product->name}}</option>` creates unnecessary markup bloat.  You never need to declare the `value` attribute if it is identical to the option's text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) which will convert the array to JSON (string) and store into the database, and when you will take data from DB it will be converted to an array again, so you can use it to display selected items in multiselect

```
class Combos extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'description' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

This feature is available for laravel 5.5 too

Comment: Is your advice already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71936813/2943403)?  Is it already provided somewhere else (better or earlier)?  It is important to not add redundant content to Stack Overflow.  If a question can be resolved by pointing someone to an appropriate pre-existing page on SO, please do that instead of answering.

Comment: @mickmackusa Hi. Yes, this could be the answer to this. But this case is easier. :)